# Horizontal scroll using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I find a tutorial or something to help me to create something like this **scrollable** area which is marked in the image below using Swift?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: -> `UIScrollView`, `UICollectionView`

Comment: This should help get you started... [UIScrollView Tutorial in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift)

Comment: @Maysam did you find how to do this? Can you assist me, I am struggle to find a tutorial about it on the internet since there is no clear name for it

Comment: @irkinosor just go to attributes inspector for the `UICollectionView` and change scroll direction to **Horizontal**.

Comment: @Maysam, thanks man. I already figured it out. :-D