# Swipe left view controller to dynamic view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I'm currently building an app that needs to be able to swipe left to the next view controller and then show random quotes dynamically from a dictionary.
I've added the current gesture recognizer from the initial view controller however I don't want the standard push segue functionality.

**How it should function:**
From swiping left you are swiped to the next view controller. From this view controller I could use a scroll view. Could I generate dynamic sub views based on the count of the dictionary or is there something else.

**Current gesture recognizer:**

```
  let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "goSwipe:")
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

I would like to be able to swipe left on the inital view controller to the next (there's only 2 VC's in the app).

Thanks

Comment: if you no need of `I don't want the standard push segue functionality` then which one you want

Comment: I want to the next view controller to slide in from the left when a user swipes

Comment: then follow vaibhav answer it suitable for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use horizontal `scrollview` by setting down its `contentSize` method x position then generate dynamic sub views based on the count of the dictionary.

Check this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061950/horizontal-scroll-using-swift).

Comment: So I would have to use scroll view on the first view controller to load in the second (sub views within sub view). Is there a way I can just use scrollview on the second view controller and not the first?

Comment: you can use `scrollview` to the second `viewcontroller` but you have to unload or navigate from first `viewcontroller` then after you can customize.. see my this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37114648/4003548) to navigate or unload view controllers