# What will be the best UI component to render array items horizontally

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have an array of 'n' number of items. I am displaying them in a horizontal stack view, having fixed width of the superview.

Issue is, when the number of items are more, then the horizontal stack view is not displaying all of them.

I need to display all the items of an array in some UI placeholder horizontally with some decent amount of spacing in between. If the items are more they should come in the next line.

Will horizontal stack view be suitable for my requirement ? If not, then which UI component should I use? Example will be appreciated.

Comment: take a look on `UICollectionView`!

Comment: May be this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061950/horizontal-scroll-using-swift

Comment: Go with UICollectionView, it will be best for your requirement

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/ A tutorial for using UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) is exactly what you're after. Use it with the standard [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout) in horizontal mode.

It will then display all its elements filling "lines" from top to bottom, thus achieving a grid layout, which seems like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of @DrMickeyLauer, If you want to make your UI look better with some eye catching animation while viewing the items then go for iCarousal.

Take a look at this URL for the sample implementation https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel